# Creating annotations in MKMapView with an altitude component

Tags: mkmapview, mkannotation, altitude, mkuserlocation

This seems to be possible because the MKUserLocation annotation is placed at the user's current altitude. However, the protocol for MKAnnotation only includes a coordinate. Is there a way to adjust its altitude as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is method :-

```
  [mapView showAnnotations:yourAnnotationArray animated:YES];
```

You can pull from an array stored in the map view:

```
  yourAnnotationArray = mapView.annotations;
```

and quickly adjust the altitude :-

```
  mapView.camera.altitude *= 1.4;
```

try multipling the cameras altitude by a fraction of one, like **mapView.camera.altitude *= .85**; for a closer viewport

Comment: Thank you, but this affects the camera, and I'm interested in adjusting the altitude of an annotation. Do you know of any way to do that?